# Plot vector in same column using ggplot

Tags: r

I have a vector:

```
a<-runif(100)
```

I would like to plot each of the values of `a` on the y axis with the same position on the x axis using dots.

I tried

```
x<-1

barplot(x,a)
```

but it gave me the error

```
Error in barplot.default(x = 1, a) : 
  argument 1 matches multiple formal arguments
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Use plot() instead of barplot() and turn the x values into a vector:

```
a<-runif(100)
x<-rep(1,times=length(a))       # x & a same length
plot(x,a,type="p")              #type = "p" : point
```

[image]

or in `ggplot2`

```
require(ggplot2)
a<-runif(100)
x<-rep(1,times=length(a))
qplot(x,a,geom="point") 
#OR
ggplot()+geom_point(aes(x,a))
```

[image]

Comment: and what if I'm using ggplot? sorry I didn't specify that

Comment: updated to show both the qplot(0 and ggplot() calls from ggplot2